# What does waiter.acquire() do in threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm doing some CPU debugging, and I'm looking at a code heatmap from vprof.

[image]

The dark green highlight represents high CPU usage.

What does the line do and when is it called? Is it from `lock.acquire()`? Or is it something from creating or joining threads?

My script creates `threading.Thread()` and uses some global locks.

Comment: IIRC, acquiring the lock = joining the thread. All the CPU usage of a subthread is not counted against the main thread, _but_ at a join you still have to wait for it to complete = you end up seeing the effect here. E.G. if you do a join() and the subthread takes 10 seconds to complete, the main thread sees 10 seconds waiting to acquire the lock. To really figure out why it's taking that long, you'd have to profile the thread itself. I am not an expert in threading so this might not be it but I ran into this exact situation recently.